# Meaning of allowed_requests keys for SSH config

Tags: ssh

I need to set the `allowed_requests (-p)` option for the `ForceCommand` keyword on `ssh` config file. `/usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server -Q requests` returns the list of available values.

```
open
close
read
write
lstat
fstat
setstat
fsetstat
opendir
readdir
remove
mkdir
rmdir
realpath
stat
rename
readlink
symlink
posix-rename
statvfs
fstatvfs
hardlink
fsync
lsetstat
limits
expand-path
```

Where can I find the meaning of each option?

I need to restrict access for a user and I'd like to understand what the tutorial I'm following is setting.

Answer (score 1):

You can find almost each option explanation over here:
https://github.com/mscdex/ssh2/blob/master/SFTP.md

Good luck with the tutorial!